# Join variable names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got multiple long variables names.

```
var easternstateconventionlocation = "someting a";
var easternstateconventiondateandtime = "someting b";
var easternstateconventionsponsor = "someting c";
```

As you can see `easternstateconvention` is common. When I'm using these variables , is it possible use the common part + the additional part and combine to create the full variable name? example:

```
var common = 'easternstateconvention';
var loc = 'location';
var spo = 'sponsor';
var dat = 'dateandtime'; 
.text('location: '+ common +''+loc+' at '+ common +''+dat);
```

My requirement is to shorten the variable names for future use.

NOTE: I'm looking for a solution to do this without changing the existing long variable names.

Comment: @JayeshChitroda Thanks for your reply. As mentioned I'm looking for a solution to do this without changing the existing long variable names.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are going to use huge ungainly variables, you should camelCase them. I guess your method might work if all of the vars values are strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a object comprise the variables, then you can fetch data using [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) from object.

```js
var obj = {
  easternstateconventionlocation: "someting a",
  easternstateconventiondateandtime: "someting b",
  easternstateconventionsponsor: "someting c"
}


var common = 'easternstateconvention';
var loc = 'location';
var spo = 'sponsor';
var dat = 'dateandtime';

console.log('location: ' + obj[common + loc] + ' at ' + obj[common + dat])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var common = 'easternstateconvention';
var loc = 'location';
var spo = 'sponsor';
var dat = 'dateandtime'; 
console.log('location: '+ [common] +''+[loc]+' at '+ [common] +''+[dat]);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4vab2006/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var common = {
    location: "someting a",
    dateandtime: "someting b",
    sponsor: "someting c"
 };

var loc = 'location';
var spo = 'sponsor';
var dat = 'dateandtime'; 
console.log('location: '+ common[loc]+' at '+ common[dat]);
```

or

```
var common = {
    location: "someting a",
    dateandtime: "someting b",
    sponsor: "someting c"
 };

console.log('location: '+ common['location']+' at '+ common['dateandtime']);
```

But U use CamelStyle. String or varialbe 'dateAndTime' it is readable from 'dateandtime'.